# Change order of indices for dictionary of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, I re-asked this question in Code Review, see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254463/data-set-with-many-variables-in-python-many-indented-dictionaries).

---

I am working with complex data sets in Python and I store the data in dictionaries. Since there are many variables I have many "indented dictionaries" with up to 4 indices of the form

```
data[key1][key2][key3][key4] = a_float_number
```

and these `key_i` can be anything from strings to floats. How can I easily rearrange this dictionary such that two of the keys are swapped? For example I want to change it to:

```
data_rearranged[key3][key2][key1][key4] == a_float_number
```

Currently I am doing this with `for` loops but it's a pain. Probably there is a better way of doing this, or my suspect is that there is a better data container that does not have this problem.

Comment: You might be able to do it with dictionary comprehensions, but I doubt it will be more readable than the `for` loops.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: I did not understand your question very well, but feels like [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can make your work a little easier?

Comment: This really sounds as [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your real task? What are you modeling?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I asked my question in Code Review, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254463/data-set-with-many-variables-in-python-many-indented-dictionaries). I was not aware of that site.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, seems to me also as an XY problem (I did not knew that term for this). I re-asked my question in a better way in Code Review, see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254463/data-set-with-many-variables-in-python-many-indented-dictionaries). I am currently working with particle detectors and each data sample has an ```x``` position, a ```y``` position, a ```channel``` , a ```variable``` and we could add a ```trigger number```, however this last quantity is the index of a list because I don't really care about it.